# Symfony2 PHP Parse error when invoking app/console cache:clear

Tags: php, symfony

Whenever I am trying to clear the cache on Symfony2 I am constantly getting the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  parse error in /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/src/MyApp/MainBundle/Services/TransactionManager.php on line 177
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/app/console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/app/console:32
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:70
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2215
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2435
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile() /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:629
PHP   8. JMS\AopBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PointcutMatchingPass->process() /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php:119
PHP   9. JMS\AopBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PointcutMatchingPass->processDefinition() /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/vendor/jms/aop-bundle/JMS/AopBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/PointcutMatchingPass.php:59
PHP  10. class_exists() /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/vendor/jms/aop-bundle/JMS/AopBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/PointcutMatchingPass.php:96
PHP  11. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /Users/Adam/Sites/MyApp/vendor/jms/aop-bundle/JMS/AopBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/PointcutMatchingPass.php:0
```

Here's what line 177 looks like:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc} 
 */
public function findAwaitingPaymentTransactionsByUserId( $dateRange = [] )
 {
   // ...
 }
```

Any idea why this is? This just happened after I upgrade my Lion OS X, before it works just fine with the code above.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Greater than or equal to 5.3?

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson I am running PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2013 19:05:08)

Comment: Set `$dateRange = []` to `$dateRange = NULL` then clear cache manually in the app/cache directory. Can you execute the app/console router:debug command afterwards without error?

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson actually I am running PHP Version 5.4.13. And yes after changing to $dateRange = NULL the error goes to the next line that has the [] issue. I can't use [] in 5.4?

Comment: I'm confused there's only one line in the code you provide that uses the short array syntax `[]`. Which line, exactly, is line 177? You have 7 lines of code there.

Comment: Exactly, what was confusing me as well.

Comment: this one:  public function findAwaitingPaymentTransactionsByUserId($userId, $page = 1, $dateRange = [])

Comment: Then you can't possibly be using PHP 5.4.13 and getting that parse error. http://3v4l.org/oFn5e

Comment: use `phpinfo()` to determine version, then post it here.

Comment: @GoogleGuy does http://3v4l.org/oFn5e apply to the Symfony framework, or just flat php? He may be getting his error from Symfonys' default Profiler that comes with standard installation and using a app_dev environment.

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson we've already established that his problem was running PHP from the command line, which was using the older PHP 5.3 binary, and that he was checking his PHP version through the mod_php Apache installation, which was using the newer PHP 5.4 binary.

Comment: Latent problem solved yes, which is minuscule. The structure of how a parser is displaying an error is irrelevant in solving why 5.3 cli is parsing `[]` incorrectly in app/console. Last I checked, assigning to `[]` is bad practice in this symfony2 context regardless of your PHP version .

Comment: I have edited the question and provided an answer so this question can help other users in the future. Please accept the answer so we have this issue solved.

Answer (score 2):

The method's default argument `$dateRange = []` uses the **short array syntax** that was introduced in PHP 5.4.

Your `PHP` command line interface uses PHP `5.3` that can't understand this syntax.

Therefore the method declaration results in a `PHP Parse error`.

Change the method to ...

```
// array() instead of []
public function findAwaitingPaymentTransactionsByUserId( $dateRange = array() )
{
    // ...
}
```

... to resolve the issue.